# Trying to use powershell to selectively erase old backup files

Tags: powershell

I am working with a drive with thousands of backup files, many of which are just cluttering space.

The program our employees use creates a backup of a spreadsheet every time they open one for editing. Each backup is a new file named according to the spreadsheet + the date + the time. We have a separate backup directory for each of our clients, and each directory has multiple spreadsheets and multiple backups of each spreadsheet.

In the end, we have a file structure filled with files like this:

```
Companyx/backup/abssheet_091210_111006.bps    
Companyx/backup/abssheet_091210_133335.bps    
Companyx/backup/xyzsheet_091210_145223.bps    
Companyx/backup/xyzsheet_100803_100332.bps    
Companyx/backup/xyzsheet_100812_111244.bps
Companyy/backup/gnu_sheet_081029_110455.bps
Companyy/backup/gnu_sheet_081029_111233.bps
Companyy/backup/gnu_sheet_081029_112355.bps
```

We only need to keep the most recent 2 backups of any particular sheet. Out of the 8 files I listed here, I would want to keep 6. The date and time in the filename is unimportant, as I can use the date and time from the file information. But the filenames cannot end up changed.

I have played around with powershell some, and I already used gci to move these to a file location of their own. I can also strip the date and time strings from the filenames. I also found a powershell script to remove all but the 2 newest files from a particular directory. But I am at a loss on how to selectively delete what I want to.

So far, I have written/modified the following code:

```
$newlist = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]
$fulllist = gci . | where {-not $_.PsIsContainer} | sort Name
$array = @()

foreach ($object in $fulllist)
{
    $string = $object.name
    $psworiginal = $string.Replace("_"+($string -split "_")[-1]," ")
    $psworiginal2 = $psworiginal.Replace("_"+($psworiginal -split "_")[-1]," ")
    $newlist.Add($psworiginal2)
}

$newlist = $newlist | select -unique
```

This gives me a list of the individual spreadsheets. But them I'm not sure how to work from that list to go back through the original list and remove all but the latest 2 backup of each spreadsheet.

Ideally, I would like to put the -Recurse parameter back in the gci call and have it go through a complex directory structure to weed out older backups in every directory.

Comment: If you have a recent Powershell (>= 3) you can specify files with `gci -File` and save the extra pipeline. If your file names are consistent for the first *y* chars, you can `Group-Object -Property {$_.name[y]}` to group the files. And finally, if you can trust your file time stamps, all of this becomes much easier.

Comment: This should point you in the right direction http://superuser.com/questions/794282/deleting-all-but-latest-revision-of-a-file

Comment: I've read this post a few times and I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do.  Probably just me though.

Comment: I finally figured out how to do what I wanted. I'm not sure it was the most efficient, but it worked well to use a hashtable to keep track of how many times each file was found. As I found a file, I checked to see if it was in the hashtable or not. If it was not, I added it with a value of 1. If it was there with a value of 1, I changed the value to 2. Otherwise, I deleted the file. If it would be helpful to see some of the specific code, I can post it.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove every file based on 'key' from each company folder except two newest one
Filtering is based on `LastWriteTimeUTC`

In this code, the `$local:allFiles = @{};` in `Filter-BackupFiles` function is a key-value hastable where THE KEY is part of filename before `12345_12345.bas` (the `fileKey` named selection in RegEx, in my example it is everything before last `_` symbol) ans THE VALUE is array of file objects (not file names). For each file I add (using `Add-Member`) an attribute for soring (in my case it is `LastWriteTimeUTC`, you can do something else in your case)

Then for each key (which is filename prefix) I sort the list of file objects and adding to removal list all except two (`$Script:KeepMostRecent = 2`) first files (this means two newest files because they were sorted by date desceding).

```
$Script:StartPath = 'D:\Test_1'
$Script:KeepMostRecent = 2;
$Script:BackupSubfolder = 'backup'
$Script:RegexFilter = '^(?<fileKey>.*)_\d+_\d+\.bps$'
$Script:SimulatingMode = $true
#In my case regex is overriden because of file names
$Script:RegexFilter = '^(?<fileKey>.+)_[^_]+\.txt$' #THIS IS DEV OVERRIDE
Function Log-Error {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$LogMessage
    )
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Error: $($LogMessage)";
}
#End of Log-Error

Function Get-Companies {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$SearchBase
    )
    $local:companyDirectoies = @()
    try {
        $local:companyDirectoies = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchBase -Recurse:$false -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object {$_.psIsContainer -eq $true} -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object {return $_.FullName} -ErrorAction Stop )
    } catch {
        Log-Error -LogMessage $([String]::Format("Error while getting companies list: {0}", $_.Exception.Message))
        return $null
    }
    return $local:companyDirectoies
}

Function Get-BackupFiles {
        Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$CompanyDirectoryPath
    )
    $local:files = @();
    try {
        $local:files = @( Get-ChildItem -Path $CompanyDirectoryPath -Recurse:$false -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object {$_.psIsContainer -eq $false} -ErrorAction Stop)
    } catch {
        Log-Error -LogMessage $([String]::Format("Error while getting Backup file list for path {0}: {1}", $CompanyDirectoryPath ,$_.Exception.Message))
        return $null
    }
    return $local:files
}

Function Filter-BackupFiles {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [Object[]]$CompanyBackupFiles
    )
    $local:allFiles = @{};
    $local:filesToRemove = @()
    foreach ($local:f in $CompanyBackupFiles) {
        $local:lastFileDate = $local:f.LastWriteTimeUtc
        $local:f | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'LastDate' -Value $( $local:lastFileDate ) 
        $local:fileName = $local:f.Name
        if ($local:fileName -match $Script:RegexFilter) {
            $local:fileKey = $Matches['fileKey']
            #Use NotCContains ir you need case-sensitive filtering
            if ($local:allFiles.Keys -notcontains $local:fileKey) {
                $local:allFiles[$local:fileKey] = @()
            }
            $local:allFiles[$local:fileKey] += @($local:f)
        } else {
            Log-Error -LogMessage $([String]::Format( "Error - the file name {0} does not match regEx. None will be processed for this list",$local:fileName))
            return $null
        }
    }
    foreach ($local:k in $local:allFiles.Keys) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor White "Checking files for key $($local:k)"
        $local:files = @( $local:allFiles[$local:k] | Sort-Object -Property 'LastDate' -Descending  )
        $local:filesToKeep = $Script:KeepMostRecent
        foreach ($local:f in $local:files) {
            $local:filesToKeep--
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor White -NoNewline "$($local:f.FullName)`t$($local:f.LastDate)"
            if ($local:filesToKeep -lt 0) {
                $local:filesToRemove += @($local:f.FullName)
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "`tMARKED TO REMOVE"
            } else {
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "`tMARKED TO LIVE"
            }
        }
    }
    return $local:filesToRemove
}

Function _main {
    $local:AllFilesToRemove = @()
    $local:companiesPathList = @(Get-Companies -SearchBase $Script:StartPath)
    if ($local:companiesPathList.Count -le 0) {
        Log-Error -LogMessage "Companies list is empty"
        return
    }
    forEach ($local:comanyPath in $local:companiesPathList) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor White "`r`n`r`nProcessing company on path $($local:comanyPath)"
        $local:companyBackupFolder = ""
        try {
            $local:companyBackupFolder = $( Join-Path -Path $local:comanyPath -ChildPath $Script:BackupSubfolder -ErrorAction Stop )
            $local:allCompanyFiles =  Get-BackupFiles -CompanyDirectoryPath $local:companyBackupFolder -ErrorAction Stop 
        } catch {
            Log-Error -LogMessage "Error getting backup files for company $($local:comanyPath) : $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
        if (($local:allCompanyFiles.Count -le 0) -or ($local:allCompanyFiles -eq $null)) {
            Log-Error -LogMessage "Company $($local:companyBackupFolder) does not have files in backup. Will ignore it."
            continue
        }
        $local:companyFilesToRemove =  Filter-BackupFiles -CompanyBackupFiles $local:allCompanyFiles 
        if (($local:companyFilesToRemove.Count -le 0) -or ($local:companyFilesToRemove -eq $null)) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Company $($local:comanyPath) does not have files to remove. Will ignore it."
            continue
        }
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor White "Company $($local:comanyPath) have $($local:companyFilesToRemove.Count) file to remove"
        $local:AllFilesToRemove += @( $local:companyFilesToRemove )
    }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor White "Totally we have $($local:AllFilesToRemove.Count) files to remove" 
    foreach ($local:f in $local:AllFilesToRemove) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor White "Removing $($local:f)"
        try {
            Remove-Item -Path $local:f -Force -Confirm:$false -WhatIf:$Script:SimulatingMode -ErrorAction Stop
        } catch {
            Log-Error -LogMessage "Error removing file $($local:f) : $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
}

_main
```

So the output will be

```
Processing company on path D:\Test_1\Company1
Checking files for key File1_Custom_Name
D:\Test_1\Company1\backup\File1_Custom_Name_bak1.txt    02/28/2016 07:07:38 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company1\backup\File1_Custom_Name_Bak2.txt    02/28/2016 07:06:38 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company1\backup\File1_Custom_Name_Bak3.txt    02/28/2016 07:05:38 MARKED TO REMOVE
Checking files for key File2
D:\Test_1\Company1\backup\File2_Bak1.txt    02/28/2016 07:07:38 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company1\backup\File2_Bak2.txt    02/28/2016 07:06:38 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company1\backup\File2_Bak3.txt    02/28/2016 07:05:38 MARKED TO REMOVE
Company D:\Test_1\Company1 have 2 file to remove


Processing company on path D:\Test_1\Company2
Checking files for key File2
D:\Test_1\Company2\backup\File2_Bak3.txt    02/28/2016 07:58:34 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company2\backup\File2_Bak2.txt    02/28/2016 07:58:31 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company2\backup\File2_Bak1.txt    02/28/2016 07:58:28 MARKED TO REMOVE
Checking files for key File4
D:\Test_1\Company2\backup\File4_Bak1.txt    02/28/2016 07:59:43 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company2\backup\File4_Bak3.txt    02/28/2016 07:58:42 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company2\backup\File4_Bak2.txt    02/28/2016 07:58:39 MARKED TO REMOVE
Checking files for key File1
D:\Test_1\Company2\backup\File1_Bak3.txt    02/28/2016 07:58:25 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company2\backup\File1_Bak2.txt    02/28/2016 07:58:22 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company2\backup\File1_bak1.txt    02/28/2016 07:58:17 MARKED TO REMOVE
Company D:\Test_1\Company2 have 3 file to remove


Processing company on path D:\Test_1\Company3
Checking files for key File2
D:\Test_1\Company3\backup\File2_Bak1.txt    02/28/2016 07:07:38 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company3\backup\File2_Bak2.txt    02/28/2016 07:06:38 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company3\backup\File2_Bak3.txt    02/28/2016 07:05:38 MARKED TO REMOVE
Checking files for key File4
D:\Test_1\Company3\backup\File4_Bak1.txt    02/28/2016 07:07:38 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company3\backup\File4_Bak2.txt    02/28/2016 07:06:38 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company3\backup\File4_Bak3.txt    02/28/2016 07:05:38 MARKED TO REMOVE
Checking files for key File1
D:\Test_1\Company3\backup\File1_bak1.txt    02/28/2016 07:07:38 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company3\backup\File1_Bak2.txt    02/28/2016 07:06:38 MARKED TO LIVE
D:\Test_1\Company3\backup\File1_Bak3.txt    02/28/2016 07:05:38 MARKED TO REMOVE
Company D:\Test_1\Company3 have 3 file to remove
Totally we have 8 files to remove
Removing D:\Test_1\Company1\backup\File1_Custom_Name_Bak3.txt
Removing D:\Test_1\Company1\backup\File2_Bak3.txt
Removing D:\Test_1\Company2\backup\File2_Bak1.txt
Removing D:\Test_1\Company2\backup\File4_Bak2.txt
Removing D:\Test_1\Company2\backup\File1_bak1.txt
Removing D:\Test_1\Company3\backup\File2_Bak3.txt
Removing D:\Test_1\Company3\backup\File4_Bak3.txt
Removing D:\Test_1\Company3\backup\File1_Bak3.txt
```